# What should I use to document my Sinatra routes?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm looking for something like RDoc that will work well with Sinatra. In addition to regular Sinatra routes, it needs to be able to handle routes that are loaded externally via 'register MyModule' and of the form:

```
Module MyModule
  def self.registered(app)
    # Description of someroute.
    app.get '/someroute' do
```

Comment: What sort of documentation are you trying produce? What aspects of your application do you want to document? Just the routes? The parameters that a route accepts? Why are comments in your source code not sufficient?

Comment: Basically the same use case as RDoc. I'd like name, description, and parameters to show up -- example usage would be a bonus. Right now the comments are in the source code, but I'd like to automatically generate separate HTML programmer documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with [yard](http://yardoc.org/). from yard's homepage:

> You can write all kinds of extensions in YARD, including ones that can understand all of the dynamic magic your framework does in its own little Doman Specific Languages (DSLs). Most importantly, it's really easy to do! There are already plugins that support frameworks like RSpec, DataMapper, **Sinatra**, and support for others are in the works.

There seems to be a plugin here: https://github.com/rkh/yard-sinatra that does at least some of what you want already.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to point out that Yard supports Sinatra routes natively since v0.7.0, so you don't need yard-sinatra anymore.

You can find more info at https://github.com/lsegal/yard/wiki/SinatraRoutes

Comment: Sadly, I did not find this to be the case. I had to `gem install yard yard-sinatra` (at present, 0.9.16 and 1.0.0, respectively) and invoke with `yard --plugin yard-sinatra`